# How do I verify Android internationalization visually?

Tags: android, user-interface, internationalization

We're facing a upcoming internationalization project for our Android app, expanding significantly on the three currently supported languages. All the languages that we're initially supporting will use existing layouts and are left-to-right, and we are already familiar with language specific setups (separate resource files etc.) as required, so fortunately nothing too exotic is in store for now.

I would like to be able to visually verify that our layouts work and that everything looks OK. Are there any good tools or best practices available for this need? Trying to find resources, I've only been able to identify tools for managing the actual string resources themselves or different platforms for sourcing translations, but nothing that would render them in their actual context for verification.

The only immediate thing that I can think of is to essentially run our test scripts with something like [this screenshot lib](https://github.com/rtyley/android-screenshot-lib), and then rinse and repeat for every language we should support. Is there a better, less work intensive and time-consuming (a single testrun times languages supported will probably take at least a few hours on a single device) approach?

Comment: In Android Studio or IntelliJ Idea you have the visual editor in which you can easily select the language currently on display. It's the flag in the top-bar.

Comment: Good tip, thanks for the hint! We just tried it out, and unfortunately even with some static layouts we have some rendering problems that never occur on any real devices. Aside from that, some content is also generated dynamically, so it doesn't fully cover our requirements.